Unreal engine: Pointer points to another address one frame later
I'm having weird a behavior with the first code block below in UE5.3, Did not test on other engine versions and I apologize if it's a beginner issue!
class MyClass
{
private:
    float* Value;
public:
    MyClass(float& InValue) : Value(&InValue) { }
    float GetValue() { return *Value; }
};

USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct MYMODULE_API FMyStruct
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
private:
    TSharedPtr<MyClass> NewClass = nullptr;
    UPROPERTY()
    float Value;
public:
    FMyStruct() { }
    FMyStruct(float InValue) : Value(InValue)
    {
        NewClass = MakeShared<MyClass>(Value);
    }
    TSharedPtr<MyClass> GetPtr() { return NewClass; }
};

I create a property of type "FMyStruct" and then Initialize it in my UObject custom BeginPlay as shown below
UCLASS()
    class MYMODULE_API UMyObject: UObject
    {
        GENERATED_BODY()
    public:
        UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadWrite)
        FMyStruct MyProperty;
        void BeingPlay()
        {
          MyProperty = FMyStruct(100.0f);
          float TempFloat = MyProperty->GetPtr()->GetValue() // Returns correct value here
          BP_BeginPlay();
        }
        UFUNCTION(BlueprintImplementableEvent)
        void BP_BeginPlay();
    };

As the comment says in the code block above, MyProperty->GetPtr()->GetValue() returns the correct value in BeginPlay when its called after initializing MyProperty
I exposed MyProperty->GetPtr()->GetValue() to blueprints to call it at BP_BeginPlay, Again, I get the correct value which is nice
However, After one or more frames MyProperty->GetPtr()->GetValue() no longer returns the correct value for some reason, Used a delay node in BP with value of 0.0 to skip a frame
After hours of debugging, Stripping down the code to the version above, and pulling my hair out I decided to look at memory addresses, It turns out the address which MyClass::Value points to is not the same after one frame of initializing MyProperty
This is how I got the address UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Address[%p]"), *ThePointer);
I honestly don't know what to search for online, Memory stuff is beyond me, But I did try and failed
Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

visual studio and gdb have a watch where you can set a breakpoint that triggers when something modifies a location in memory, you should use that, unfortunately that won't work if you have a memory corruption.

Where is TSharedPtr<MyClass> used? If the pointer is corrupted and it being marked as a shared pointer, it seems it gets destroyed at some point. Try Ahmed's advice. If not, track its destruction.

My experience is with UE1 and UE2 (I know, I am a dinosaur), not the new ones, but back when dinosaurs roamed the Earth there was a Destroyed() event that acted as a destructor event after Destroy() was called where you could do clean-up and so on. If the same exists in UE5 (or if not, you can just use the C++ destructor ~MyClass()), put something a UE_LOG() call. It doesn't matter what you write, it's meaningless. You only need it to put a breakpoint and attach a debugger. Then when it hits, check the callstack to see what destroys your object.

@TheNomad TSharedPtr<MyClass> is created and used within FMyStruct
I did try Ahmed's advice but I don't think I did it the correct way because it sometimes keeps breaking everwhere, and the Value ptr Address stayed the same, I will give it another go later!
Also afaik the game should crash If I try to derefrence a null pointer, but I do not experience any crashes or errors.
Regaring Destroyed(), I have no issues with my object destruction, I access "MyProperty" within its life time which is the same as the game itself atm

I didn't say MyProperty. I said to track MyClass, because that's the pointer that gets garbled. That's the destructor I told you to monitor with a breakpoint so you can see where it gets triggered from.

My bad!, I've added the log and break point, It only hits when I close the game, I assume we don't care what calls the dtor at this point?

MyClass::Value most probably creates a dangling pointer. You are doing 2 very dangerous things: 1. Storing a raw pointer without precautions; 2. Using address-of operator(unary & op). To what Value points, might have long died when you try to use it. Odd output can be a symptom of UB, which your code is very likely to exhibit. Either make MyClass::Value a value(not pointer) or totally redesign your code; no 3rd options.

FMyStruct was being copied and destroyed multiple times for reasons I do not know, So I overrode = operator and updated the properties with the new struct, Especially the pointer that points to the struct value
FMyStruct& operator=(const FMyStruct& Other)
{
    Value = Other.Value;
    NewClass = Other.NewClass;
    if (NewClass.IsValid())
    {
        NewClass->Value = &Value; // I made it public for testing purposes
    }
    return *this;
}

This is a walkaround code and is probably bad, And I think having to do this defeats the purpose of my original code, which is having only 1 true struct, I think I may have to reconsider my design
Edit:
After reading more I came up with this code
FMyStruct& operator=(const FMyStruct& Other) // Couldn't compile without this
{
    if (&Other == this) return *this;
    NewClass = Other.NewClass;
    return *this;
}

FMyStruct& operator=(FMyStruct&& Other)
{
    Value = Other.Value;
    NewClass = Other.NewClass;
    if (NewClass.IsValid())
    {
        NewClass->Value = &Value;
    }
    return *this;
}

What happens at MyProperty = FMyStruct(100.0f); in BeginPlay of UMyObject If I understand correctly is it calls default ctor for lValue, Custom ctor for rValue, and then FMyStruct& operator=(FMyStruct&& Other) in lValue with rValue as the parameter, Please correct me if I'm wrong!
